# React testing library: My mocked redux store is empty

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-hooks, react-testing-library, redux-toolkit

I cannot figure out why on render my mock redux store is empty. The component will render, but it has a conditional useEffect on a selected value from the redux store that I need to test, but the selected value is always empty despite the fact I send it in.

Here is my test:

```
// Mock redux
jest.mock("react-redux", () => {
    return {
        ...jest.requireActual("react-redux"),
        useSelector: jest.fn(),
        };
});



describe('Display', () => {

    const mockState = {
        value: "",
        valueList: ["test-1", "test-2"]
    };

    const mockStore = configureStore();
    const store = mockStore(mockState);
    
    it('Renders deeply', ()  =>  {

        
        render(
            <Provider store={store}>
                <Display/>
            </Provider>
        )

        expect(screen.getByText("test-1")).toBeTruthy()
    })  
});
```

Here is the component:

```
function Display() {
  const value = useSelector((state) => state.data.value)
  const list = useSelector((state) => state.data.valueList) 
  const [rows, setRows] = useState([])

  useEffect(() => {
    const temp = []
      list.forEach((item) => {
        ......
      })
      setRows(temp)
  }, [list])

  return (
    <Container>
      { !value && 
        <Container >
          <p>Placeholder</p>
          { !rows.length ? ....  : 
            <div>.....</div>
          }
          </Container>
      }
    </Container>
  )
}
```

However, despite all of this the valueList is always empty when the test is run in the component. Does anyone know why this might be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Don't partial mock `useSelector`, even the `react-redux` package. Your mock implementation will break the functions of the third-party package.
2. If you are using the [`redux-mock-store`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-mock-store) package to create the mock store, you didn't provide a correct `state`.

E.g.

`index.jsx`

```
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';

export const Display = () => {
  const list = useSelector((state) => state.data.valueList);
  console.log(" ~ file: index.jsx:5 ~ Display ~ list:", list)
  return null;
};
```

`index.test.jsx`:

```
import { render } from '@testing-library/react';
import React from 'react';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import configureStore from 'redux-mock-store';
import { Display } from '.';

describe('75622227', () => {
  test('should pass', () => {
    const mockState = {
      data: {
        value: '',
        valueList: ['test-1', 'test-2'],
      },
    };
    const mockStore = configureStore();
    const store = mockStore(mockState);

    render(
      <Provider store={store}>
        <Display />
      </Provider>
    );
  });
});
```

Test result:

```bash
 PASS  stackoverflow/75622227/index.test.jsx (10.247 s)
  75622227
    ✓ should pass (40 ms)

  console.log
     ~ file: index.jsx:5 ~ Display ~ list: [ 'test-1', 'test-2' ]

      at Display (stackoverflow/75622227/index.jsx:5:11)

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        11.019 s
```